# getMaxAmplitude() alternative for Visualizer

Tags: android, audio

In my app I allow the user to record audio using the phone's camera, while the recording is in progress I update a Path using time as the X value and a normalized form of `getMaxAmplitude()` for the y value.

```
float amp = Math.min(mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude(), mMaxAmplitude)
                 / (float) mMaxAmplitude;
```

This works rather well.

My problem occurs when I go to play back the audio (after transporting it over the network). I want to recreate the waveform generated while recording, but the MediaPlayer class does not possess the same `getMaxAmplitude()` method.

I have been attempting to use the Visualizer class provided by the framework, but am having a difficult time getting a usable result for the y value. The byte array returned contains values between -128 and 127 but when i look at the actual values they do not appear to represent the waveform as I would expect it to be.

How do I use the values returned from the visualizer to get a value related to the loudness of the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Your byte array is probably an array of 16, 24 or 32 bit signed values. Assuming they are 16 bit signed then the bytes will be alternating hi-byte with the MSB being the sign bit and the lo-byte. Or, depending on the endianness it could be lo-byte followed by the high byte. Moreover, if you have two channels of data, each sample is probably interleaved.  Again, assuming 16-bits, you can decode the samples something in a manner similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < numBytes/2 ; ++i)
{
    sample[i] = (bytes[i*2] << 8) | bytes[i*2+1];
}
```

According to the documentation of `getMaxAmplitude`, it returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call.  I guess this means the peak amplitude but it's not totally clear from the documentation.  To compute the peak amplitude, just compute the max of the abs of all the samples.

```
int maxPeak = 0.0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples ; ++i)
{
    maxPeak = max(maxPeak, abs(samples[i]));
}
```